error setting margins with geometry
I have what should be a simple question -- I am trying to set margins in my document to 1in all around. My full preamble is below. I'm rendering to pdf using the Texifier program, which I like because it renders in real time, but I just started using it. The margins look correct in the footnote, but the body text has much wider side margins (so the footnote text extends about 1/2 inch beyond the body text). I really need to whole document, body and footnotes, to have the 1-inch margins.
The issue persists whether or not I'm using the double spacing.
Is it maybe something to do with default settings in Texifier?
\documentclass[12pt]{article}\title{My Title}

%Layout
%\usepackage{setspace}
%\doublespacing
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

%Graphics and Tables
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}

%Bibliography/references
\usepackage[style = authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}


\author{My Name\thanks{My acknowledgments.}
}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}


\maketitle

\abstract{My abstract.}



you have not specified a page size so you have 1in margins for the default US Letter paper, but if you then print on something else such as A4 the margins will be off.

Thank you. I am using letter paper, so that's not the issue. That also doesn't explain why the footnotes would have different margins than the body.

well as you have provided no example that shows the problem (or in fact shows any output at all) it's hard to say what your issue is. Please fix the provided code to b ean example of the problem.

Note that in article  , abstract  is an environment so the fragment you posted is equivalent to \begin{abstract} {My Abstract} with no \end{abstract} so the entire document will be in the abstract and set with larger margins, as for a quotation environment.

You're probably experiencing this:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[%
  margin=1in,
  showframe,% <- for debugging
]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}% to add mock text

\title{My Title}
\author{My Name\thanks{My acknowledgments.}}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\abstract{\lipsum*[10][1-4]}

\lipsum

\end{document}


You can see that there's no space between the abstract and the following text. The reason is simple: you need
\begin{abstract}
<Text of the abstract>
\end{abstract}

Full example.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[%
  margin=1in,
  showframe,% <- for debugging
]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}% to add mock text

\title{My Title}
\author{My Name\thanks{My acknowledgments.}}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum*[10][1-4]
\end{abstract}

\lipsum

\end{document}



This fixed it, thank you!!
